# VBA - Creating a "Color Check Range" to Reverse Loop

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2016

Currently have a reverse loop looking for `cells.font.strikethrough = true`

Once found, I'm using that cell as a starting point for my `.find` to find the first cell above that has an `Interior. Color = RGB(0,0,0)` and copy/pasting that value to the destination first, then offsetting the cell that has a strikethrough by a column and deleting this entire row of data.

For the sake of my awful communication lately:
Parent cell = black background
Child cell = Every cell below the parent that does not have a black background

The cells with a black background can never have a strikethrough/be deleted at the same time as some of the child cells, because not all child cells will be moved to the other worksheet at the same time.

Data populates to this workbook like so:

```
 Parent
 child
 child
 child
 Parent
 child
 child
 child
 child
 child
```

etc.  the # of child cells are unknown for each parent.

Taking the example above, when all child cells have been moved/deleted for both parents this results in the 2 parents located above/below one another with no way to remove them other than manually deleting the rows.  Like so:

```
Parent
Parent
```

Leading me to my question of wanting a "parent cell color check" of sorts

Summary:

While reverse loop searches for strikethroughs, the macro will eventually cross a cell with a black background

Once that happens, check above that cell for another black background, and continue checking above until it hits a cell without a black background, then I want to delete all consecutive black background rows.

The only immediate problem I can think of this situation:

```
Parent
Parent
Parent
Child (no strikethrough)
```

I think the above logic would end up deleting the parent of the child that has yet to be removed, which I don't want and I'm not sure how to prevent.

Child cells will always be located below the parents, so maybe another bit of code checking above and below the first parent to see if child exists, if no child then use that position as the starting range for the parent check?  I have no idea, my brain is hurting and this is due in two days!

Apologies for the long rambling!  Here's what I'm working with right now.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim ipWS As Worksheet, compWS As Worksheet
Dim compDest As Range, rrCell As Range
Dim i As Integer
Dim alastRow As Long

Set ipWS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("In Processing")
Set compWS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Completed")


alastRow = ipWS.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row


Dim rackRng As Range
Dim cellRng As Range

Set compDest = compWS.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

Application.FindFormat.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)


For i = alastRow To 1 Step -1

            
            If Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 1)).Font.Strikethrough = True Then
           
                Set rackRng = ipWS.Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 1).End(xlUp)).Find("*", , , , , xlPrevious, , , SearchFormat:=True)
                    rackRng.Copy compDest
                        Application.CutCopyMode = False
                
                Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)).Copy compDest.Offset(0, 1)
                    Application.CutCopyMode = False
                
                        Set compDest = compDest.Offset(1, 0)
                    
                    Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 1)).EntireRow.Delete
            End If

Next i
            With compWS.Range("A:P")
                .Font.Strikethrough = False
                .ColumnWidth = 25
                .Font.Size = 14
                .WrapText = True
                .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
                .VerticalAlignment = xlVAlignCenter
            End With

End Sub
```

UPDATE

This picture shows the strikethrough cells being "completed", thus needing to be transferred to the "Completed" worksheet.

[image]

With my current code programmed to the button, this is the result on the "Completed" worksheet.

[image]

Leaving the "In Processing" sheet looking like the picture below.

[image]

Because all child cells for "12/3/2020 110" and "12/3/2020 96" have been removed, I'm looking for a way to add code to the button that removes the 2 parent cells (only when ALL child cells have been moved to the "Completed" worksheet)

Answer (score 0):

### Copy and Delete With Format Criteria

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub updateData()
    
    Const ProcName As String = "updateData"
    On Error GoTo clearError

    ' Source
    Const srcName As String = "In Processing"
    Const srcFirst As String = "D10"
    ' Destination
    Const dstName As String = "Completed"
    ' Workbook
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
  
    ' Define Source First Cell.
    Dim cel As Range
    Set cel = wb.Worksheets(srcName).Range(srcFirst)
    ' Define Source Range assuming data is contiguous with an empty column
    ' to the right, and an empty row at the bottom. Data adjacent
    ' to the left and to the top is allowed.
    Dim rng As Range
    With cel.CurrentRegion
        Set rng = cel.Resize(.Rows.Count + .Row - cel.Row, _
            .Columns.Count + .Column - cel.Column)
    End With
    
    Dim CopyList As Object
    Set CopyList = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
    Dim DeleteList As Object
    Set DeleteList = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
    
    Dim i As Long          ' Source Counter
    Dim cCount As Long     ' Copy Counter
    Dim dCount As Long     ' Delete Counter
    Dim iCopied As Boolean ' Interior Color Row Copied
    Dim iRow As Long       ' Interior Color Row
    Dim sRow As Long       ' Strike Through Row
    
    ' Write the row numbers of the rows to be copied and/or deleted
    ' to the array lists.
    iRow = -1 ' Necessary for the second 'If' statement's logic to work.
    For Each cel In rng.Columns(1).Cells
        i = i + 1
        If cel.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) Then
            If i - sRow - 1 = iRow Then
                dCount = dCount + 1
                DeleteList.Add iRow
            End If
            iRow = i
            sRow = 0
            iCopied = False
        ElseIf cel.Font.Strikethrough Then
            If Not iCopied Then
                cCount = cCount + 1
                CopyList.Add iRow
                iCopied = True
            End If
            cCount = cCount + 1
            dCount = dCount + 1
            CopyList.Add i
            DeleteList.Add i
            sRow = sRow + 1
        End If
    Next cel
    
    If cCount > 0 Then
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Dim CopyRange As Range ' ByRef
        Dim DeleteRange As Range ' ByRef
        Dim RowNumber As Variant ' Has to be 'Variant'.
        ' Write to Destination Worksheet.
        For Each RowNumber In CopyList
            buildRange CopyRange, rng.Rows(RowNumber)
        Next RowNumber
        With wb.Worksheets(dstName)
            CopyRange.Copy .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 1)
            With .Range("A:P")
                .Font.Strikethrough = False
                .ColumnWidth = 25
                .Font.Size = 14
                .WrapText = True
                .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
                .VerticalAlignment = xlVAlignCenter
            End With
        End With
        ' Delete rows in Source Worksheet.
        DeleteList.Sort
        For Each RowNumber In DeleteList
            buildRange DeleteRange, rng.Columns(1).Cells(RowNumber)
        Next RowNumber
        DeleteRange.EntireRow.Delete
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        MsgBox "Number of copied rows: " & cCount & vbLf _
            & "Number of deleted rows: " & dCount, vbInformation, "Update"
    Else
        MsgBox "No rows deleted.", vbInformation, "Update"
    End If

ProcExit:
    Exit Sub

clearError:
    Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "': Unexpected Error!" & vbLf _
              & "    " & "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf _
              & "        " & Err.Description
    Resume ProcExit

End Sub


Sub buildRange( _
        ByRef BuiltRange As Range, _
        AddRange As Range)
    If Not AddRange Is Nothing Then
        If Not BuiltRange Is Nothing Then
            Set BuiltRange = Union(BuiltRange, AddRange)
        Else
            Set BuiltRange = AddRange
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion if you saw the previous comment.  User error.

Comment: However, I changed srcFirst cell to "A1:A10" for testing purposes.  And I called the updataData sub from the cmd button and nothing happened.  Apologies, I started vba ~2 months ago whereas I understand what the code is doing, there's some sections I'm not familiar with at all.  I will update my post with pictures if that that helps fill my limited knowledge gap.

Comment: `srcFirst` has to be set to `A1` or where ever the data starts: one cell only. It's always a good idea to upload an image or two e.g. before and after.

Comment: Apologies again, I should have done that in the first place.